# I am curious as to what game engine Football Manager / EA Sport Fifa Manager uses for it's interfaces.?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am bringing a real life management, tycoon / sim game to the drawing board and would like to start with the user interfaces like Football Manager / Airport Tycoon.

I also want to do an eye candy type top down city view as in SimCity / Cities in Motion.

Lastly a 3D interaction with potential AI customers as well as an open auction house where you bid against AI and Human Competitors.

I know a bit of Java, very familiar with Unix,HTML,PHP and the fundamentals of Unity 3D.

If anyone could help point me in the right direct on what game engine could be used if any?

Many Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you're asking in quite general terms about game engines.

In answer to your original question, Football Manager, EA Sports Fifa Manager, Sim City, Cities in Motion all (I believe) use a custom game/graphics engine as compared to an off-the-shelf/middleware solution such as Unity or Unreal engine.

You've mentioned you're familiar with the fundamentals of Unity 3D, I'd recommend you focus your attention there as this is a popular game engine for developing games and I believe it has everything you'll need to get started in game programming and development.

Further questions would be more appropriate on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the response.
I've been on Unity for about 3 months now, still obviously learning and the "props" available will suit the last 2 areas of the game (Auction House and Top Down City View).  My only concern with Unity was with a stable UI.  I can do a work around with the UI but was looking at the FM interfaces due to their simplicity for the user.
Thanks for your help

Comment: No problem :) The FM interface is indeed quite simple and slick to the user but has been developed from many years of iterations of the FM engine. I'm not an expert in Unity but it appears it has built in support and tutorials for 2D UI elements http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui